# windows 10 google calendar DAY view show YESTERDAY

Tags: html, windows, calendar

I'm trying to include a "Google Calendar" to show TODAY on my homepage. It works except that it always shows YESTERDAY. I'm using this code:

```
<html>
<BODY>
<iframe src='https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=1&amp;showDate=1&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=1&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=Kalender@Gyrstinge.dk&amp;color=%23691426&amp;mode=DAY&amp;ctz=Europe%2FCopenhagen' style='border-width:0' width='1300' height='700' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know, what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: If you try my code, you can see that it always show YESTERDAY and not TODAY.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the image attached, it is showing TODAY, not sure why it is not working on your end.

The code used :

```
<html>
<BODY>
<iframe src='https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=1&amp;showDate=1&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=1&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=Kalender@Gyrstinge.dk&amp;color=%23691426&amp;mode=DAY&amp;ctz=Europe%2FCopenhagen' style='border-width:0' width='1300' height='700' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using my code ? - If you are, what are your timezone or anything else you think can be different from my setup (in Denmark). btw. in Denmark it is now 18.12.2021 and this calender is showing 17.12.2021

Comment: yes, exactly the one you have provided.

Comment: Is the date 17.12.2021 where you are ?

Comment: When I'm running the code it always show YESTERDAY, but when I click on TODAY it is showing TODAY as it should. Why is it not showing TODAY from the start ?